# to-infinitival subordinate clause

Tags: grammar, infinitives, subordinate-clauses, infinitive-constructions

saw a sentence in the class's slide:
"Missy began to think when will he arrive."

I think "to think when will he arrive" and "when will he arrive" are two subordinate clauses in this sentence. However, I get confused about their functions. (I identify both of them are objects of the main clause but not sure). Or do I need to consider 'to think when will he arrive“ as only one clause?

Comment: I wonder whether some punctuation isn’t missing from a possible original *Missy began to think, “When will he arrive?”*

Comment: No, there's no punctuation in the PowerPoint actually...

Comment: How would you bracket the syntax?  It's ambiguous with proper names.

Comment: I think 'he' refers to another person instead of the subject 'Missy'. This sentence is about the subordinate clause. I am thinking that [when will he arrive] is a content clause, and [to think when will he arrive] is a to-infinitival clause. However, what I am confused about is I am not sure whether [when will he arrive] is an embedded clause, or do I need to treat the [to think when will he arrive] as only one clause

Comment: The sentence is malformed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the sentence only makes sense if "when will he arrive" is a quotation. The common practice is to put it in quotation marks, as @tchrist suggests. I can't tell you why this author chose not to.

Comment: It's an ungrammatical sentence, and what it's intended to mean is unclear (which is common for ungrammatical sentences). As usual, Powerpoint is not the best place to get your grammatical information.

Comment: @Tsuki If the subordinate interrogative clause has no inversion, then it's either ungrammatical or poorly punctuated.